# Regex Breadcrumb output

Tags: regex, breadcrumbs

I need help in removing the last string in breadcrumb using regex.

Breadcrumb examples

```
Home > category > subcategory1 > subcategory2 > subcategory3 > itemname<br>
Home > category > subcategory1 > subcategory2 > itemname
```

Output should be

```
Home > category > subcategory1 > subcategory2 > subcategory3<br>
Home > category > subcategory1 > subcategory2
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be arbitrary HTML and, as such, is a fine candidate for using XML parsing to solve your problem. [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and learn.

Comment: So, what have you tried? You should know SO is not a coding service